# Using font awesome offline in ejs file in Node

Tags: node.js, font-awesome

I'm using font-awesome online in ejs file in express,

```
<head>
    <title>Node Authentication</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <style>
        body        { padding-top:80px; word-wrap:break-word; }
    </style>
</head>
```

I downloaded font-awesome zip folder from its website, and copied in Public folder in my express structured node app, and changed it for:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

And it doesn't look the same way, and I get some errors (failed to load resources...). My question is: How I include font-awesome in my ejs file, to be used offline??

Comment: Are you using `app.use('/', express.static('public'))`? If that's the case it's probably a reference issue - what's the folder structure under `public` - should the `href="/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"`?

Comment: I have this in my app file: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); And in public I have font-awesome folder

Comment: What's the URL for the ejs-rendered file? I'm guessing the href in your link should probably be '/font-awesome-4.7.0...'

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, I have other css links working fine in my ejs. I wonder what is the purpose of all the files in the font-awesome folder, with all those .woff and .ttf, if I'm not including it in my ejs... I'm having a conceptual problem I think ; )

Comment: Your other files are linking outside your project completing to a CDN. Try different urls in your browser to see with one pulls up your css font-awesome file (e.g. `localhost:****/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`)

Comment: I think the font-awesome css file generally includes those .woff and .ttf on it's own (via @import)

Comment: Font-awesome is also available via CDN: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/